# Next.JS slow initial load due to SSR api request

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to fetch data from the server side using SSR. unfortunately the initial loading time is awful, around 6s.
i tried to use both getServerSideProps and getStaticProps. however, the results remains the same.
it there a way to bypass that or to call the API from the FE would suit the situation better?

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { getCountries } from '../infrastructure/http/client';
import { Navbar } from '@/components/navbar/navbar';
import { FilterSection } from '@/components/filter-section/filter-section';
import { CardsSection } from '@/components/cards-section/cards-section';
import { Store } from '@/state/store';

export async function getServerSideProps(context : any) {
  const getCountriesData = await getCountries();
  const countriesData = await JSON.parse(getCountriesData);

  return {
    props: {
      countriesData,
    },
  };
};

// Maybe i dont need an api call for the entire page, will try to move it to the 
// store
export default function Home({countriesData} : any) {

  // pass the data received from getServerSideProps
  const { data } = useQuery('todos', getCountries, { initialData: countriesData });
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head> 
        <Navbar />
        <Store >
          {/* TODO ---- */}
          {/* Routing */}
          <FilterSection />
          <CardsSection countriesData={countriesData} />
        </Store>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: which version of next are you using ?

Comment: i'm using 13.1.4

Comment: If you cannot make the `getCountries` faster, you can make a request and get the data in client, instead of doing it on the server. Make a HTTP request to an endpoint. If you want it to do it on the server, the other option would be to use server components. See [Next 13 `app` directory beta docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/getting-started).